# JavaMelody: @net.bull.javamelody.Monitored annotation not showing Statistics for Classes or Methods

Tags: java, monitoring, cdi, java-melody

we followed the JavaMelody User Guide https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide, and annotated a method of our CDI Bean with `@SessionScoped` accordingly (`@net.bull.javamelody.Monitored`) as described in the **Session Business facades (ejb-jar.xml file if EJB3) or CDI** session of the User Guide. We are using JavaMelody Version 1.92.0

However, when we deploy the application and call the `/monitoring` endpoint, everything is displayed, but no information on the monitored method. Also, placing the annotation on the class has no effects, i.e., no statistics.

Are there other prerequisites to meet in addition to get the statistics to be collected and displayed?
I will appreciate any help, please.

We did just as described above; annotate the method of the CDI Bean with `@net.bull.javamelody.Monitored`

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/issues/1149

Fixed in javamelody 1.94.0